# Trouble sanitizing an array from input

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection, sanitization

I have trouble sanitizing my array and am hoping someone can take a look!

here is my input:

```
<input type="text" name="courseno[]" id="courseno" size="12" />
```

here is my function to sanitize my data:

```
function sanitizeData ($datastring) {
    if (is_array($datastring)) {
        foreach ($datastring as $indivdata) {
            $indivdata = sanitizeData($indivdata);
        }
    }
    else {
        $datastring=trim($datastring);
        $datastring=htmlspecialchars($datastring);
        $datastring = mysql_real_escape_string($datastring);
        return $datastring;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['courseno'])) {
    $courseno = sanitizeData($_POST['courseno']);
}
```

the `$courseno` data won't post when I try to sanitize the array, while all my other data gets posted.  When I don't sanitize `$courseno`, the data gets posted to the database just fine.

Comment: Normally, the data is sanitized after it is posted, ie in the server, how are you trying to sanitize it and then post??

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would help if `sanitizeData()` returned a value when `$datastring` is an array.

```
if (is_array($datastring)) {
    foreach ($datastring as $indivdata) {
        $indivdata = sanitizeData($indivdata);
    }
    // you need to actually return something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `if (is_array($datastring))` test, you assign the output of the `sanitizeData` call back to `$indivData`. So if the input contains an array, a real value is never returned. `$courseno` will be assigned a NULL value. You'd probably want to change it to something along the lines of this:

```
function sanitizeData ($datastring) {
    if (is_array($datastring)) {
        $result = '';
        foreach ($datastring as $indivdata) {
            $result .= sanitizeData($indivdata);
        }
    return $result;   
}
else {
    $datastring=trim($datastring);
    $datastring=htmlspecialchars($datastring);
    $datastring = mysql_real_escape_string($datastring);
    return $datastring;
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['courseno'])){
    $courseno = sanitizeData($_POST['courseno']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put your text box outside the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a variable scope problem.

```
function sanitizeData ($datastring) {
    // This is needed to hold the value between function calls ...        
    static $indivdata = array();         

    if (is_array($datastring)) {
       foreach ($datastring as $indivdata) {
          $indivdata[] = sanitizeData($indivdata);
       }
       return $indivdata;
   } 
   else {
     $datastring=trim($datastring);
     $datastring=htmlspecialchars($datastring);
     $datastring = mysql_real_escape_string($datastring);

     return $datastring; 
     } 
  }   
 // $courseno will be an array now.
 if (isset($_POST['courseno'])){
       $courseno= sanitizeData($_POST['courseno']);
 }
```

Unless I missed something at this late hour, it seems your function does not return the data array.
There are a couple of ways to solve this, but the above code should get you in the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I tried this out and came up with this error: "[] operator not supported for strings in